# Why the following character pointer types are being considered incompatible?

Tags: delphi, types

Consider the following snippet:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  {$REGION 'Sealed declarations'}
  type WCh = WideChar; // (1)
  type Str = ^WCh;     // (2)
  { this routine accepts character pointer }
  procedure Baz(Param: Str);
  begin
  end;
  {$ENDREGION}
  { this one too, but character pointer type used directly }
  procedure Bar(Param: PWideChar);
  begin
  end;
  { this constant should be compatible with strings and character pointers }
  const FOO = 'FOO';
begin
  Bar(FOO);  // compiles!
  Baz(FOO);  // BAH! E2010 Incompatible types: 'Str' and 'string'
end;
```

How do i resolve this problem preserving both structured typing in declarations and the clarity and readability in the usage (i hope for no heavy typecasting)?

**NB:** By "sealed declarations" i really mean it. I prefer to not amend it unless it is absolutely necessary.

Internal handling of conversion between `string` and `PChar` varies from version to version, so environment might matter - i encountered this problem in Delphi XE.

Comment: Very hard to understand why you don't use WideChar and PWideChar directly

Comment: And you can answer your own question simply by referring to the documentation: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Type_Compatibility_and_Identity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Rob Kennedy correctly noticed in comments, the question is about conversion from string *literal*, not string *type*.

To simplify coding Delphi allows implicit conversion from string literal to `PChar` type and `PChar` aliases.

To avoid typecasting you can use

```
  type Str = PWideChar;
```

or use distict type

```
  type Str = type PWideChar;
```

I have not noticed any difference in string literal --> PWideChar implicit conversion in Unicode Delphi versions (2009 and above).

Comment: Could you please expand on rules violation? String constant is compatible with **both** `string` and `PChar`, internally it is not a real long string yet but an array [0..X] of Char

Comment: As an illustration try to convert true constant to typed constant and when Bar will produce compile error too. More likely, *Delphi allows implicit conversion from PChar to string*, not vice versa.

Comment: @user just read the docs I linked to in my comment to Q, all explained there

Comment: @user539484 - The statement that string constants are stored as plain array of char generally is not true; the compiler stores a string constant in long string format if the constant is referenced as string (not PChar).

Comment: @Serg, please correct me if i got you wrong: first declaration preserves type identity with WideChar, second declaration creates pointer type, distinct but compatible with PWideChar, and since new pointer type is no longer identical to PChar/PAnsiChar/PWideChar - syntactic sugar with automatic string conversion also no longer in effect?

Comment: @user539484 `Str = PWideChar` declares `Str` as alias type for `PWideChar`; `Str = ^WideChar` is not an alias type for `PWideChar`. Implicit string --> PChar conversion applies only to PChar/PAnsiChar/PWideChar and aliases

Comment: @Serg, thank you! That was my misconception: special types and aliases vs. just compatible ones.

Comment: How does the `Bar` call violate anything?

Comment: @David, although it's explained in the documentation, unless you know what to look for, it's not exactly obvious. In particular, you need to notice that the documentation mentions the three built-in character-pointer types specifically by name. It's not obvious that that means other, manually defined, character-pointer types don't count. Serg's *answer* doesn't even mention that. It's not until his most recent comment that the real explanation comes out. The answer has nothing to do with string-to-PWideChar conversions because there is nothing here with type `string`.

Comment: @Rob string/PChar compatibility is a Delphi feature, not found in standard Pascal (not all Pascal is Borland Pascal, I studied Pascal on PDP-11 clone, and it was much closer to standard).

Comment: I see. I didn't notice you were talking about Pascal as distinct from Delphi. I assumed you were talking about Delphi since this is a Delphi question. Why bring up Pascal at all?

Comment: @Rob That's why I didn't up-vote. Even with the edit the answer doesn't shed much light. A good answer would include a link to and extracts from the documentation, and the necessary commentary to interpret the docs.

Comment: @David - I guess there are no links or documentation. I am thinking about writing a blog post related to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your `WCh = WideChar` definition creates a type alias for `WideChar` — they have *type identity* — but the subsequent `Str = ^WCh` definition does *not* create a type alias for `PWideChar`. When `$T+` is in effect, they're compatible and assignment-compatible, but those aren't good enough in this situation. They are still distinct types.

The `FOO` constant is a *string literal*. The [documentation for assignment compatibility](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Type_Compatibility_and_Identity#Assignment_Compatibility) says what types a string literal can be assigned to: "PAnsiChar, PWideChar, PChar or any string type." `Str` is not a string type. It's a pointer type, but it's not `PWideChar`, despite how similar their definitions are.

The type of a string literal adapts based on context. When the compiler needs a `PWideChar`, the string literal is a `PWideChar`. When the compiler needs an `AnsiString`, it's an `AnsiString`. (If the compiler needs both those types, then the literal will be stored in the program both ways.) String literals aren't assignable to your `Str` type, so, according to the error message, the compiler apparently chooses `string` as the type for the string literal in that situation. You can type-cast it to one of the other built-in types, but the better solution would be to avoid using custom-defined character-pointer classes at all.

Comment: In the fact, `$T+` was the first thing i tried, w/o any success, tho. Yeah, i finally decided to break the seal and add some duplication for intrinsic type to save an ability to use string literals and constants.